# Error when trying to use WebSockets on JBOSS with Jetty 8.1.8 & Netty 3.2.7

Tags: websocket, jetty, jboss7.x, netty

I have tried to create a websocket servlet on JBOSS with Jetty 8.1.8 & Netty 3.2.7
I am using a client that works with Tomcat so i dont think it is the problem
I keep receiving Null Pointer Exception whenever I try to connect to the server side websocket servlet
the exception occurs in Jetty's "WebSocketFactory.java" file
after the following line: 
    AbstractHttpConnection http AbstractHttpConnection.getCurrentConnection()
the getCurrentConnection function returns null and following this line tries to use one of its function's(which obviously throws the exception).

here is my code:
    package com.microfocus.entrypoint.servlets;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OWMFAsyncJboss extends WebSocketServlet {


         @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
          private final Set<ChatWebSocket> users = new CopyOnWriteArraySet();

          @Override
          public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest arg0, String arg1) {
                    try
                    {
                    return new ChatWebSocket();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                              System.console().writer().write("error");
                    }
                    return null;
          }

         @Override
          protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    super.service(request, response);
          }

          class ChatWebSocket implements WebSocket.OnTextMessage
          {
                    WebSocketConnection connection;

                    @Override
                    public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1) {
                              users.remove(this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOpen(Connection arg0) {
                              ChatWebSocket.this.connection= (WebSocketConnection) connection;
                              users.add(this);
                    }

                    public void onMessage(byte frame, byte[] data,int offset, int length)
                    {
                    // binary communication not needed
                    }
                    public void onMessage(byte frame, String data)
                    {

                   }
         }

}
```

and here is the exception:

> 17:36:01,728 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/benAsync].[AsynchServlet]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-7) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet AsynchServlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.upgrade(WebSocketFactory.java:225) [jetty-all-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketFactory.java:361) [jetty-all-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:107) [jetty-all-7.6.2.v20120308.jar:7.6.2.v20120308]
>             at com.benPackage.entrypoint.servlets.OWMFAsyncJboss.service(OWMFAsyncJboss.java:58) [classes:]
>             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]

any help or direction that might help me would be appreciated
thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.

First, you say in your question you are using Jetty 8.1.8, but your stacktrace shows you are using Jetty 7.6.2.v20120308.

Next, jetty-websocket requires access to the Jetty internal connection upgrade mechanism in order to break out of the Servlet API spec rules.  Something that is not possible in this hybrid JBoss + Jetty environment you have described.

A solution could be to run Jetty on a different port on the same machine and just proxy the UPGRADE requests to this other Jetty instance.  But JBoss has very limited support for UPGRADE requests and `101 Switching Protocols` responses.

Comment: first of all thanks ! the Jetty version is my mistake - i copied the error message from the stack and tried to change the jetty jar to a more advanced one - but it showed me the same error, is there a way to place the jetty in the same port and machine that the jboss is located on? Maybe install some jboss plugin or module i dont know, because proxy to another port is not an option for now, and again thanks!